Getting resource not found error ( error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found. )
So I am working on an app which supports API Level 25 till date and we cannot upgrade the API Level as of now. I want to integrate a new dependency but when I try to build the app I am getting these errors
../../.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml  

error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}  

error: resource android:attr/font not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/font not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)} 

 error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)} 

 error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}  

error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found., sources=[/Users/amanjn38/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.4.0.aar/724f3e33e3a015bf03bd0343723b0f2d/res/values/values.xml:214:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

I have tried playing around with appcompat dependency, which is implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0' right now, but nothing seems to work.
I am expecting a way around to make this work.
